# Does hortonworks support Hue?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hue, ambari

Recently i heard that apache Ambari support Hue (which is a Cloudera component) but I'm not sure if I can use it on my HDP 2.5, and if it can work well for my cluster with no problem (I use Ambari 2.5)

Does HDP support Hue?

Answer (score 1):

We believe they officially stopped, but as Hue is compatible with any Hadoop, people still install it the clusters: http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Based on [HDP 2.5.0 Release Notes](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_release-notes/content/ch_relnotes_v250.html) it does.  At the bottom of the page, you'll see:

> Additional component versions:
>
> - Cascading 3.0.0
> - Hue 2.6.0